# Why does my shopping cart total not work using onclick and toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cart

Here is a link to my problem-child shopping cart: http://CODEX32.com/simpleShoppingCart with a link to view its page source at the top left portion of the page.

The specific issue is that the running total is not working properly.  Any direction would be extremely appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
try {
function grandTotal() {     
running_total = window.sku9448Total + window.sku2976Total;
document.getElementById('total').value = '$' + running_total;
}
} catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Why are you using eval?

Comment: I tried simply: window.sku9448Total + window.sku2976Total ... and that didn't work (grasping at straws)

Comment: The page is updated and same NaN and random results appear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `consol.log(window.sku2976Total)` revealed `window.sku2976Total` is `undefined`.

Your problem is that the variables are not defined at the moment that you are trying to access them so the result leads to `undefined` variable shown as `NaN` when appended.

So, either set the variables in the beginning to 0 or check if the variables are defined before using them.

You can do it like:

```
if(typeof variable_here === 'undefined'){
   // your code here.
};
```

or

```
if(! variable_here){
   // your code here.
};
```

Comment: thank you.  Now, the big question ... I am trying to run the two functions using onclick to give me the grand total with this: <a id="updateCart" onclick="updateSku2976('8skuTNSeS',document.shoppingCartForm.sku2976Quantity.value);updateSku9448('20skuNFoEE',document.shoppingCartForm.sku9448Quantity.value);" href="javascript:void(0);">Add to Cart</a>.  but only one will work at a time.  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I would suggest that you bind the click event to the DOM element form javascript rather than changing the onclick attribute of the element. Thats known as [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Other than that, you could try to combine the functions in one. I can't see any issue by viewing only this part of the html.

Comment: Thank you.  I created another post that has the rest of the code ... As I don't mind giving credit where it is gratefully due.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398772/run-2-javascript-functions-onclick-for-a-grand-total-from-their-sum