# Google's Simple Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, cart

Here is the simple shopping cart I was looking for: http://code.google.com/p/jscart/wiki/Example. Thank you everyone for your help.  All the notes led me to rethink and ponder ... hmm, I wonder if someone out there has already done something similar ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your "currentStateOpened".
If you addd your first Item it will be set to false and thus the second item will have as total price "0".

However, you probably should code the whole thing differently. I hope that is for training purposes to get started with JS and you don't plan on using that in real life :)

Comment: Hi @ben-a, I was hoping to make it really easy to PowerPoint it for training purposes.  My hope was to show how by clicking on a product image, you can dynamically show their current tally.  Then they would have the option of increasing their quantity. And, if they just did not want it, they could click the product again.